# ReactJs Input: onKeyPressed does not fire for backspace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, input-mask

I'm trying to create a mask in React, however `onKeyPressed` it does not fire for backspace or delete. It won't allow deleting an input.

here's my code:

```
export default class InputField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { text: this.props.text };
        this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
    }

    onKeyPress(event) {
        console.log(event.key);
        var mask = this.props.mask;
        var currentText = this.state.text || "";
        var invalidButtonPress = false;
        switch (mask) {
          case "number":
            if ("0123456789".indexOf(event.key) > -1) {
              this.setState({ text: currentText + event.key });
            } else {
              invalidButtonPress = true;
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        if (invalidButtonPress) {
          // allow for arrow keys, tab and backspace.. but if none of those and invalid reset
          this.setState({ text: currentText }); // Reset back to original text
        }
    }

    render() {
        <Input
            type={this.props.type || "text"}
            value={this.state.text}
            mask={this.props.mask}
            onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
        >
        ...
    }
}
```

I have tried `onKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp`, which do detect backspace, but these events I am unable to affect the value of the input by `this.setState({})`.

Comment: You don't need to break after return from switch case. It's redundant code.

Comment: looks like u r using a custom input component.. u have to check the keypress event of the custom component.

Comment: yes, i've already check the keypress event and console log it but it returns nothing only when using backspace or delete. It can't detect backspace or other special characters

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried onKeyDown and OnKeyUp, which do detect backspace, but these events I am unable to effect the value on the input by this.setState({})

React allows you to mix and match these events. So you can keep your `onKeyPress` for adding to your input and use `onKeyDown` or `onKeyUp` to delete.

Comment: How will mixing and matching help? if I catch the backspace on keyDown or keyUp, keyPressed will fire after it and still revert my input as the event.key is not equal to 0123456789?